# Allow users to update Email and Password from client app for Keycloak 16

Tags: keycloak

We are using Keycloak 16 and we have custom themes for our client login. We would like to provide a feature for users to update their own email ID and Password from client apps(they can be redirected to our custom themes)

I know there we can customise Account management with Keycloak themes, please suggest if any such ready-made customisations are available.

Can this be achieved with REST Apis but Keycloak since version 12 has removed account APIs, please suggest if there is any way we can do this with non-admin Rest Apis.